# Plotting two dataframe time-series on same graph with different sampling (and using double Y axis)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two data frames that look like:

```
                  Temp [Degrees_C]  Cond [mS/cm]    
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss             
2020-01-28 03:00:59 14.553947   19.301285   
2020-01-28 08:00:59 14.501740   19.310037   
2020-01-28 13:00:59 14.425415   18.531609   
2020-01-28 18:00:59 14.414717   16.155998   
...
```

And this:

```
                    CONDUCTIVITY    Temp [C]
DATE TIME           
2020-01-28 03:00:00     18.240  15.761111
2020-01-28 04:00:00     18.147  15.722222
2020-01-28 05:00:00     17.930  15.722222
2020-01-28 06:00:00     17.873  15.666667
...
```

I want to create one plot using these two data sets, they should share the same x-axis as the date-time, and two different y-axes (one for temperature and one for conductivity).
However, since the sampling is different for both of them, I'm not sure how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the dates to match between the two datasets, I would use [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html).  Alternatively, you could use [`dt.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html), but that could lead to some issues if you aren't sure the rounding will work.

To plot two y-axes, you are looking for [`ax.twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

str1 = """
2020-01-28 03:00:59, 14.553947,   19.301285   
2020-01-28 08:00:59, 14.501740,   19.310037   
2020-01-28 13:00:59, 14.425415,   18.531609   
2020-01-28 18:00:59, 14.414717,   16.155998   
"""


str2="""
2020-01-28 03:00:00,     18.240,  15.761111
2020-01-28 04:00:00,    18.147,  15.722222
2020-01-28 05:00:00,     17.930,  15.722222
2020-01-28 06:00:00,     17.873,  15.666667
"""

colnames1 = ['date','cond','temp']
colnames2 = ['date','temp', 'cond']
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str1), header=None, names = colnames1, parse_dates=['date'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str2), header=None, names = colnames2, parse_dates=['date'])

#Offset to even seconds
df1.date = df1.date - pd.DateOffset(seconds=59)

#plot
ax = df1.plot(x='date',y='temp', label='df1', color='k', ls = '--')

#Create second y axis
ax_tw = ax.twinx()
df1.plot(x='date',y='cond', ax = ax_tw, label='df1', color='k', ls='-')
df2.plot(x='date',y='temp', ax= ax, label='df2', color='red', ls='--')
df2.plot(x='date',y='cond', ax = ax_tw,label='df2', color='red', ls ='-')
ax.legend()
```

which returns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This matplotlib documentation webpage shows a simple example how to plot with double y axis: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

You wrote you have a data frames, which sounds like you use pandas for data handling. You might simply cast your data to numpy arrays and follow the example.

Comment: The main issue is not the two-scale Y axis, but the different time sampling for the x-axis.